# SharePoint CSOM API - Current site is not a tenant administration site

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, site-collection, sharepoint-admin-center

We use this code to iterate tenants site collections:

```
string url = $"https://{initialDomainName}-admin.sharepoint.com";
var context = new ClientContext(url);
context.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
{
    string accessToken = GetAccessToken();
    e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
};

var tenant = new Tenant(context);
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint("0", true);

context.Load(spp);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

and it works correctly for almost all of our tenants, but for some of them we get this exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException "Current site is not a tenant administration site."

We have Sites.Manage.All permissions for our app.

Comment: Has that permission level definitely been granted on the tenants where you receive the error?

Comment: @CallumCrowley For sure